# SKPhysicsBody optimization

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics

I have a 2D sidescrolling game. Right now, in order to jump, the player must be touching the ground. Therefor, I have a boolean, isOnGround, that is set to YES when the player collides with a tile object, and no when the player jumps. This generates a LOT of calls to didBeginContact method, slowing down the game.

Firstly, how can I optimise this by using one big physics body for the tiles on the floor (for example clustering multiple adjacent tiles into one single physics body)?

Secondly, is this even efficient? Is there a better way to detect if the play is on the ground? My current method opens up a lot of bugs, for example wall jumping. If a player collides with a wall, isOnGround becomes YES and allows the player to jump.

Comment: You are testing on a device right?

Answer (score 1):

Having didBeginContact called numerous times should in no way slow down your game. If you are having performance issues, I suspect the problem is probably elsewhere. Are you testing on device or simulator?

If you are using the Tiled app to create your game map, you can use the Objects Layer to create a individual objects in your map which your code can translate into physics bodies later on.

Using physics and collisions is probably the easiest way for you to determine your player's state in relation to ground contact. To solve your wall issue, you simply make a wall contact a different category than your ground. This will prevent the isOnGround to be set to YES.

Comment: > To solve your wall issue, you simply make a wall contact a different category than your ground. This will prevent the isOnGround to be set to YES.   Well here's the issue, this game's tiles are dynamic, meaning the player can pick up and set down tiles.

Comment: @ThorCorreia You will need to determine if the tile is a wall or floor depending on where the user places down the tile.

Comment: @ThorCorreia - I don't know your exact code structure but it would make sense to set the tile's category bit mask based on the current circumstance. For example, picking up a floor tile and placing it on the wall would change the bit mask from floor to wall.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the physics engine to detect when jumping is enabled, (and this is what I used to do in my game). However I too have noticed significant overhead using the physics engine to detect when a unit was on a surface and that is because contact detection in sprite kit for whatever reason is expensive, even when collisions are already enabled. Even the documentation notes:

> For best performance, only set bits in the contacts mask for
>   interactions you are interested in.

So I found a better solution for my game (which has 25+ simultaneous units that all need surface detection). Instead of going through the physics engine, I just did my own surface calculation and cache the result each game update. Something like this:

```
final class func getSurfaceID(nodePosition: CGPoint) -> SurfaceID {
    //Loop through surface rects and see if position is inside.
}
```

What I ended up doing was handling my own surface detection by checking if the bottom *point* of my unit was inside any of the surface *frames*. And if your frames are axis-aligned (your rectangles are not rotated) you can perform even faster checks to see if the point is inside the frame.

This is more work in terms of level design because you will need to build an array of surface frames either dynamically from your tiles or manually place surface frames in your world (this is what I did).

Making this change reduced the cpu time spent on surface detection from over 20% to 0.1%. It also allows me to check if any arbitrary point lies on a surface rather than needing to create a physics body (which is unnecessary overhead). However this solution obviously won't work for you if you need to use contact detection.

Now regarding your point about creating one large physics body from smaller ones. You could group adjacent floor tiles using a container node and recreate a physics body that fits the nodes that are grouped. Depending on how your nodes are grouped and how you recycle tiles this can get complicated. A better solution would be to create large physics bodies that just overlap your tiles. This would reduce the number of total physics bodies, as well as the number of detections. And if used in combination with the surface frames solution you could really reduce your overhead.

I'm not sure how your game is designed and what its requirements are. I'm just giving you some possible solutions I looked at when developing surface detection in my game. If you haven't already you should definitely profile your game in instruments to see if contact detection is indeed the source of your overhead. If you game doesn't have a lot of contacts I doubt that this is where the overhead is coming from.

Comment: Having set collisions, how can a node be inside of another?

Comment: @sangony I'm sorry I don't understand the question.

Comment: @sangony Oh I think I understand. The surface frames mark a region where jumping is allowed. So it needs to be positioned above the node, not on top of it. You can think of the surface frame as "painting" the surfaces of your game using a series of rectangles. In my case I use 3-point rotatable rectangles. To check if a position is inside one of these rectangles is much faster than relying on sprite kit's contact detection or using the allContactedBodies property.

Comment: @sangony Any convex polygon could be used for the surface frame. I chose to use rectangles because they were accurate enough for my game and fast.

Comment: Interesting. So in effect you have created your own custom contact methods. You said you were getting some impressive speed increases. Were those due to not using physics at all or just not using the contacts?

Comment: @sangony Surprisingly, just not using contacts. The reason why I even needed the change was because on the iPhone 4s the game lagged. Once I added in this change it ran full 60 FPS. What I don't understand is that collisions enabled are fine, it's just the contacts! Seems like possibly a poor optimization on Sprite Kits end. What's funny is I often thought about replacing the Sprite Kit Physics with a custom physics engine because their physics engine is not open source so you can't turn off expensive computation/tweak it. And if there was ever a bug with the physics you could easily fix it.

Comment: @sangony However I love Sprite Kit's graphics drawing power. Auto-generated atlases, automatic support for metal. The SKActions system and lastly support for Mac. They are amazing features and the reason why I use sprite kit.

Comment: Agreed. SK has a number of unresolved issues, the physics engine being one of them. I too have had a number of issues and performance mysteries in regards to contacts in the past. I will certainly try out your suggestion in my next SK project and see how well it performs.

Comment: @sangony You are absolutely right. Btw Have you had a chance to test iOS 9/El Capitan Sprite Kit yet? I'm anxious to test my game on it.  Really hoping that there are not going to be any new bugs. Maybe they improved the performance and fixed the bugs :)? Also they added the new whole-module compiler optimization mode. Interested to see how that works as well.

Comment: Have not tried beta iOS 9 or new OS X. Did that for iOS 8 and regretted it big time! I am excited about all the new SK features and optimizations but I will wait to try them until everything is officially released. You should really join our group, the SKA http://www.skymistdevelopment.com/sprite-kit-alliance/  You would be a welcome addition. Email Skyler, our evil supreme overlord ruler, so he can join you up :)  skyler@skymistdevelopment.com